# How to change the text size and text color of spinner list items?

Tags: android, spinner

I am using one spinner that has some list of item.I want to change the text color and text size of the items.I am using android entries to fill the list.Please find the below code for clarification.

Spinner code :

```
   <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#456789"
            android:popupBackground="@color/title"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
            android:entries="@array/spinnerItems"/>
```

Comment: "I want to change the text color and text size of the items" -- that is controlled by your `SpinnerAdapter`.

Comment: Create custom text view xml for that and use that text view in `Spinner Adapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom spinner item view.  I.E here is simple_spinner_item.xml from Android:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

From there, you'll need to pass that view into your adapter.  For example:

```
new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {context.getString(R.string.item1), context.getString(R.string.item2)});
```